# Install xampp in vb.net during setup and deployment

Tags: vb.net, xampp

Please bear with me. Is there any chance to create a installer package with xampp in vb.net? Let's say I have a software to install and `xampp` is required to install since it is in local server. So if there is any alternative please help! Here is a sample scenario. 
Let's say i'm the user I will download the installer for `race todo list(software)` after downloading, i'll click the installer and start installing. So will the installer do the installing of `xampp`? How?

Answer (score 0):

You could just include the xampp installer with where you can download your installer. For example, you could put the xampp installer executable with the installer for your program in a compressed zip file and use the following code to launch the xampp installer while in your own installer. Say the xampp installer is called "xmpinst.exe"

```
Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\xmpinst.exe")
```

This will start the xampp installer provided it is in the same directory as your installer is running from...

Comment: And also how can I configure it? For example I want to set `Apache 2.2` and `phpmyadmin` in `Automatic` in the service?

Comment: You cannot do that without accessing the program... You would have to launch the installer separately and do it from there or use the xampp zip compressed version which you can choose the version to download from the website...